# failed to update a static property

Tags: c#, .net, static

```
public static class clsCounter
{
    static int count;

    public static int Counter
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }
}
```

The above is the static class that is used to record a number.

Also, I have two projects within a VS2010 solution, one of which is a class library. In one of these classes, I have got the following code which uses `clsCounter`.

```
if (clsCounter.Counter == 0)
    countIES++;
else
    countIES = 0;
```

Now, in the other project, I set some new values to `clsCounter`

```
clsCounter.Counter = 50;
```

However, for some reason, I am not able to set clsCounter.Counter to 50, thus I always get `countIES++`. The code looks okay to me, and I have no idea what's wrong with it? Can anyone help?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I wonder if it has something to do with the scope of projects within vs solution?

Solution Structure

Solution

- ExcelAddIn

  - Form1.cs => (clsCounter.Counter = 50)
  - ...
- ClassLibrary

  - clsCounter => (static class)
  - ...

EDIT 2:

`clsCounter.Counter = 50;` is actually running in `backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)` event. Could this be a possible issue?

EDIT 3:

I have uploaded a sample project that seems to be able to reproduce the same problem. Here's the shared link: => http://www.4shared.com/folder/sInyNWyi/_online.html

What I would like to do here is to populate a cell with value, `Other case` after the button 'set value' is pressed. The static class and UDF can be found in the class library.

Note that, to be able to use **=testFunc()** within excel addin, need to find it in automation server list and enable it. So just go File->Option->Addin->Under Manage Add-in->Click GO->Automation->Ebale ClassLibrary1.UDF

Please also check if the option "**Register for COM interop**" has been enabled or not before launching the debugger. To find it, go ClassLibrary1 Property -> Build -> Under Output, check **Register for COM interop**.

Comment: Unclear in what project the pieces of code are.

Comment: Could you try to create a minimal (but complete) sample that has the same behavior?

Comment: is there any chance `clsCounter` is defined in more than one place?

Comment: Append a little structure at the end of my question.

Comment: are those lines maybe running on different threads?

Comment: @hcb oh, that reminds me of one thing, `clsCounter.Counter = 50;` is located in backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) event. WIll this cause any issues?

Comment: i don't think so, static classes are supposed to be the same across different threads, unless you define the threadStatic attribute

Comment: @hcb hmm then it's totally beyond me. I really don't know what to do now. I am quite frustrated :(

Comment: I think the word `ExcelAddIn` makes a lot of difference, maybe Excel loads these into AppDomains?

Comment: Are you sure that event RunWorkerCompleted was raised?

Comment: the code which uses clsCounter is it run twice for some reason? if yes it would be clear why you end up with clsCounter++

Comment: @ Sll Yes, the event RunWorkerCompleted was raised coz I get to see popup message within.  @xOr How can I know if clsCounter has run twice?

Comment: @svick yes you can find the code via the link now.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if anyone can have a look at the sample code.

Comment: =testFunc() is not visible and accessible, then, in a project you downloaded

Comment: @Artur you couldn't find it in the automation server list? There is no ClassLibrary1.UDF?

Comment: @woodykiddy i have a problem adding udfs for Excel 2007 (no other version is installed)...

Comment: @Artur Oh probably because the project was created as Excel 2010 add-in project, it failed you. Give me a moment, and I will create 2007 version.

Comment: @Artur pls check that link again, and choose another project and see if you can run it on your machine this time. I have used 2007 add-in project for that project instead of 2010 one. Hope that would work. Also, Can you pls check the property of ClassLibrary1 before you launch the debugger? If I didnt enable Register for COM interop yet, please go ClassLibrary1 Property->Build->Check Register for COM interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think I found a workaround although it had nothing to do with the static. I was kinda inspired by the idea of using cookies in the web apps.

Similarly, all I need to do here is:

store a value in a temporary text file, by doing

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\countIESValue.txt", value);
```

in the "set value" button click event handler.

And read the stored value whenever I need it from the above text file and assign it to a local variable.

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\countIESValue.txt"))
{
    string val = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\countIESValue.txt");
}
```

The text file can also be deleted after done processing. In this way, I don't have to worry about any scope or application domain issues, although the permission of writing files is required. I am glad it worked pretty all right for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your static property:

```
public static class clsCounter
{
    private static int count;

    public static int Counter
    {
        get { 
               Debug.WriteLine("Counter viewed"); 
               return count; 
            }
        set { 
               Debug.WriteLine("Counter Changed from {0} to {1}", count, value);
               count = value; 
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can watch your debugger and set breakpoints on the counter which will allow you to find out which part of the code is modifying your counter inappropriately.  A static counter will be initialised "at some time" before it is accessed.  I would say you are setting the counter and something somewhere is immediately incrementing it before you read it.

Comment: I have got the message, saying "Counter Changed from 0 to 50" the moment I clicked the button "set value". But when you type formula =testFunc() in the cell again, the result is still unchanged. Hmm it's really weird. I wonder if you can download the source code and probably run it?

Comment: You have the messages.  So you can work out your problem now.  If it is being incremented then you will see where that occurs.  If someone modifies your "Counter" then you will see a debug message.